# Не отправляется string по сокету (TCP socket: передаю из qt в Java)

Tags: java, c++, qt, сокет, tcp

Я хочу отправить string через qt в мое java приложение.

```
(QTcpSocket* socketMessage;)
```

---

В qt я вызываю функцию для отправки сообщения

```
//Ф-ция отправки сообщения в Java
void sendJava::sockSendMes(){

    qDebug() << "sendJava: отправка сообщения в Java";

    socketMessage->write("Close java app");
    socketMessage->flush();

    socketMessage->waitForBytesWritten(500);
    socketMessage->waitForReadyRead(500);

}
```

Но после выполнения внутри java ничего не приходит. Действие как висело на строке

```
mesFromQt = readSocket.readLine();
```

так и висит. Часть кода java:

```
String mesFromQt = null; //Сообщение полученное от Qt
            try {
                System.out.println("Closer: read socket ");
                mesFromQt = readSocket.readLine(); //Считать данные из Qt
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            
            System.out.println("Message from Qt: "+mesFromQt);
```

Но при этом если я использую close:

```
socketMessage->close();
```

то, тогда сообщение доходит до java, но в таком случае я не могу отправить сообщение от java в qt. Вернее я его отправляю, а qt принимает null или "".

Код принятия сообщения в qt:

```
QByteArray data = sendMesJava.socketMessage->readAll();

qDebug() << data;
```

Приходит "" - ничего.

код Java - отправка сообщения:

```
            System.out.println("Closer: write mes in Qt");
             
            String mesForQt = "killProcess"; //Сообщение для Qt
            
            try {
                writeSockQt.write(mesForQt); //Отправка сообщения в Qt
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Подскажите как можно сделать так, чтобы была возможность и отправлять данные от qt в приложение java, и следом java могла отправить сообщение qt. При этом не используя функцию close (потому что я им наверное закрываю возможность записи) и что-то подобно, заранее спасибо.

Comment: ¿А зачем там `socketMessage->waitForBytesWritten(500);`? Там же всего несколько байт отправлено. И символа завершения строки нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал так: socketMessage->write("Close java app\r\n"); 
Теперь qt может отправить сообщение именно в нужный момент в Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в чём:

```
readSocket.readLine()
```

Читает строку, т.е. ждет символ переноса строки `\n`

Поэтому в сокет нужно писать так:

```
socketMessage->write("Close java app\n");
```